# Auto complete box for movies

Tags: jquery, html, json, xml, autocomplete

Is it possible to make an auto-complete box using data from www.omdbapi.com(xml or json)? Or do you know any other way to make a movie auto-complete box?
I would be grateful if you could find me a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: You can call api on textbox `keyup` or `keydown` event, receive the results and using some js autocomplete framework, you can create autocomplete dropdown.

Comment: Questions of the form "is it possible?" are not appropriate. Anything is possible. You need to show us what research you have done, and we can guide you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this tutorial about how to create such an autocomplete functionality:
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/08/simple-movie-search-app-jquery-ajax/

Although the demo doesn't work anymore (probably because they have updated the API), the principles about how to do it are still the same and you can apply this to omdb api.

Try to do it yourself and if you have any troubles, you can ask it on stackoverflow. Don't expect stackoverflow to write the whole solution for you.